# Enable pinch to zoom in chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, gestures, pinchzoom

Currently I am working on a Packaged Chrome app which incorporates a Google Map. I am however unable to zoom using pinch. Also 'normal' zoom on a webpage doesn't work.

All pages (and maps) I use are zoomable with pinches if I open them in Google Chrome directly, but I don't seem to get it working in a packages app. Any ideas? Might this be a permissions or WindowOptions problem?

Working on Mac 10.11.3. Chrome version 48.0.2564.116

Simple example (dropbox link): [zoomtest](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwgl1mmxxn0zsvj/zoomtest.zip?dl=0)

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Zoom test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        innerBounds: { width: 800, height: 600 },
        state: 'normal'
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
    width: 400px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This page is zoomable in Google Chrome if opened directly,
but not if run as an app.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us how you embed the map.

Comment: I also have it with non-maps pages. When opening them directly in Chrome I can zoom on the HTML page with pinches. But in a Chrome app I can't. Is there some setting I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps. Still, show a minimal example.

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwgl1mmxxn0zsvj/zoomtest.zip?dl=0)
I will try to post the code here as well

Comment: Well, without running, that's simply [not going to work](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy). Has nothing to do with zoom - it just won't work _at all_.

Comment: Basically, can you provide an example of zoom not working _without_ any external content?

Comment: The above example does work. Google maps loads just fine because of the sandbox settings, which is preferred, I think. I will change the example to not use maps for clarity.

Comment: Now with a clear minimal example I can upvote the question; unfortunately, I don't have an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by using the following function:

```
function mapTouchFix(){
  if("ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch){
    navigator = navigator || {};
    if(navigator.platform!='MacIntel'){
      navigator.msMaxTouchPoints = navigator.msMaxTouchPoints || 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently this spoofed  Chrome / Google maps to enable the pinch gestures